How to compare Word docs versions directly inside Azure Devops without having to download both versions locally?
For my internship, I need to find an efficient way to compare docs like you would with code versions, directly inside azure devops if possible. Converting Word to Markdown could also be a solution but there seems to be some downsides to that.
So I would like to know how your company manages that problem or how you would proceed.
My company is willing to pay if a good solution already exists.
I could download both versions to compare but it seems to be a hassle for the other devs to do that for every doc.
I have seen pandadoc and review board and am currently trying to figure out how it works and if it fits my problem.

Currently, it doesn't support viewing DOCX/DOC files in Azure DevOps, we can't compare Word docs versions directly inside Azure DevOps. There have been some feature requests asking for Doc/Docx support, you can follow them for the update.

Enable Microsoft Office documents in Azure DevOps Wiki
Add support for more file viewers in TFS web client

To view the version history and compare versions of a word file, it's suggested that you use SharePoint in Microsoft 365. See View the version history of an item or file in a list or library for the detailed info.
